# Why does my JS onscroll function dont work when I write the JS code in my JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, function

My JS onclick function work when I put the code in script tags in the html file under the div. But I want to put the script in to the JS file and this dont work.

HTML:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>

   <div class="col-sm-6" id="test" onscroll="scrollback()">
        <?php  $controller->getEvents(); ?>
   </div>
```

JS (js/javascript.js):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

   var isCounting = false;

    function scrollback() {
        if (isCounting == false) {
            isCounting = true;
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    document.getElementById("test").scrollTo({
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0
                    });
                    isCounting = false;
                }, 1000);
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: You've placed your `scrollback()` function inside a jQuery "ready" handler, so it's not visible globally.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your answer. I placed the code outside the "$(document).ready(function () {}" handler but it still not worked.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would elaborate on what "not worked" means. Are there errors in the developer console? Does *anything* happen? Have you done any debugging to check to see if the function is being called?

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the script tag at last in body tag. This ensures the HTML elements loads first then the Js file loads.

Comment: But I dont want the JS code in my hole HTML file, I want it in my JS file :)

Comment: Place the script src link tag at last in body tag

Comment: It's called by an HTML attribute. It isn't trying to bind before the DOM is ready.